# How can I change Google's crawl rate?

Tags: googlebot

I just switched servers; from a shared host to EC2 and have been seeing better performance.  I guess Google noticed this too and cranked up the crawl rate, unfortunately for me it is currently too high and I can't handle it across my sites.  How can I turn it down?  I did some reading and people say you can do this in Google Webmaster Tools however the area where you switch the crawl rate setting has the message: "Your site has been assigned special crawl rate settings. You will not be able to change the crawl rate."

I depend on Google for the majority of my traffic so I don't want to block them via robots.txt I just want them to simmer down a tad.  Is there a way to do this via robots.txt or some other method?

Comment: This question is off-topic here, as it has nothing to do with programming or programming tools. Voting to migrate to [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com) where it is more appropriate.

Comment: @KenWhite - there's 188 googlebot questions on StackOverflow that disagree with you

Comment: Andrew, I'd bet the majority of them were pior to the creation of webmasters. It doesn't matter, though - read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Also, just because Google is mentioned in your search results doesn't mean the questions weren't programming-related in some way. Yours isn't. :)